# How to implement custom StringProperty in JavaFX?

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, binding

I would like to implement custom [StringProperty](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html) that reads/writes values from/to external source (database). I want this class support all JavaFX features like uni- and bi- directional binding so that I could connect this to `TextField`.

Unfortunately, I can't select class to start from.

`StringPropertyBase` looks over-defined, because it already contains `String` field. Simultaneoulsy, `StringProperty` itself appears too hollow.

Also, I see no any directions on what to implement.

For example, I found, that when property is "bound" it contains instance of `Observable` inside from which it takes it's value. This is probably not for me, because my data source is external. Can JavaFX maintain properties, which supports only "binding out" or "binding bidirectional", but not "binding in"?

Also, I don't see any clues on how to support bidirectional binding...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but I think you could achieve something similar with JPA (keeping the annotations on the getters).

Comment: Doing this would be a rather bad idea, since a connection to a database would take more time to complete than a event handler setting the value from the application thread should require to return. Use a "normal" property instead to represent the current state of the client and update that property on messages from the server/send updates from the ui to the server. There's absolutely no need to create a `StringProperty` for this purpose and doing so would most likely result in code that is hard to reuse and a weird class design.

Comment: You can't avoid reading from database by turning properties "normal". The only thing you can do is caching, and it is already done. So, the question persists: how to implement own bean properties?